# Change Posts per page count

Tags: posts, pagination

In the wordpress **settings** => **Reading** => **Blog pages show at most**  [input field] **posts**

I have it set to 3 posts at the moment.

On my index, date archives, tag archives, category archives, search results, etc... All pages that use the loop and paging, it shows 3 posts per page now.

My goal is to be able to have different number of results for different pages.  ON my index maybe have 3 posts but on search results or archives, show a different number of results per page.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will do it: (add to your theme's functions.php)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  'set_posts_per_page'  );
function set_posts_per_page( $query ) {

  global $wp_the_query;

  if ( ( ! is_admin() ) && ( $query === $wp_the_query ) && ( $query->is_search() ) ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );
  }
  elseif ( ( ! is_admin() ) && ( $query === $wp_the_query ) && ( $query->is_archive() ) ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
  }
  // Etc..

  return $query;
}
```

Comment: Is `set` a method of `$query`?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Yes. In fact, is_search() and is_archive() are too, which is now a little more clear after updating my answer with info gleaned from this great post: http://www.billerickson.net/customize-the-wordpress-query/ That article also notes that we'll have the $wp_query->is_main_query() method in WP3.3, which is pretty cool.

Comment: Awesome man! Thanks a lot for the great post. I never knew these methods, and I used to drill down the object / array to change / set values. Good for on the fly hacks! +1 for you!

Comment: Since when was it necessary to never change it if is_admin dashboard? Looks like it doesn't sync the "Number of items per page:" in screen options in WP possibly resulting in pages you can't page to.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on the answer above: hook `pre_get_posts` is fetched by reference, thus it does not require a `global` call or a `return`call.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  'set_posts_per_page'  );
function set_posts_per_page( $query ) {

  if ( ( ! is_admin() ) && ( $query === $wp_the_query ) && ( $query->is_search() ) ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );
  }
  elseif ( ( ! is_admin() ) && ( $query === $wp_the_query ) && ( $query->is_archive() ) ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
  }
  // Etc..

}
```

Comment: There is a problem with your code too as using the global $wp_query will resort into memory wastage but you can't call undefined various $wp_the_query

Answer (score 0):

Using $GLOBALS['wp_query'] or just $wp_query

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  'set_posts_per_page'  );
function set_posts_per_page( $query ) {

  if ( ( ! is_admin() ) && ( $query === $GLOBALS['wp_query'] ) && ( $query->is_search() ) ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );
  }
  elseif ( ( ! is_admin() ) && ( $query === $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] ) && ( $query->is_archive() ) ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
  }

  return $query;
}
```