# Custom post type query with pagination doesn't work

Tags: theme-development, pagination

I've one custom post type name of "videos" now I want to query in a custom template from that CPT. Here is my custom post register code

```
register_post_type( 'videos',
        array(
                'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __( 'Videos' ),
                        'singular_name' => __( 'Video' ),
                        'add_new' => __( 'Add New Video' ),
                        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Videos' ),
                        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Videos' ),
                        'new_item' => __( 'New Videos' ),
                        'view_item' => __( 'View Videos' ),
                        'not_found' => __( 'Sorry, we couldn\'t find the Videos you are looking for.' ),
                        'featured_image'  => __('Video Thumbnail'),
                        'set_featured_image'  => __('Set Thumbnail Image'),
                        'remove_featured_image' => __('Remove Thumbnail Image'),
                        'use_featured_image'    => __('Use Thumbnail Image'),
                ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'menu_position' => 14,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-video-alt2',
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'videos' ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' )
        )
);
```

And I've queried and tried a lot of ways. but didn't luck. here are my query codes.

```
 <?php            
        $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                  global $paged;
                  global $wp_query;
                  $temp = $wp_query; 
                  $wp_query = null; 
                  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
                  $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=2&post_type=videos'.'&paged='.$page);
                  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
            ?>
<!--Single Video-->
<div class="col-xl-2 p-0">
  <div class="single-video-area clearfix">
    <div class="single-video-data">
      <div class="single-video-thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('video-testimonial') ?></a>
        <div class="single-video-thumb-overlay">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/controls_play.png'); ?>" alt=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>                
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--/ Single Video-->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!--Pagination -->
<div class="video-template-pageination">
    <?php the_posts_pagination(array(
    'screen_reader_text'    => ' ',
  ));?>

</div><!--/ Pagination -->  
<?php 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
```

Now Pagination working fine and show after 2 posts. here is screenshot

[image]

But now the problem is when I click 2 or 3 from this pagination then show 404 error page 
here is another screenshot for 404 page

[image]

I've resaved permalink a lot of times. but still didn't luck. I've copied some query codes from my previous project, which project I did succeed about is topic (CPT with Pagination) but with this project didn't luck.

Already I've researched a lot of time. 
here is some article which I've followed, for example

[Custom post type pagination 404 fix?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22528/custom-post-type-pagination-404-fix)

[Change Posts per page count](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-posts-per-page-count/30763#30763)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920110/wordpress-custom-post-type-pagination-links-return-404

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364294/pagination-on-custom-wp-query-in-wordpress-takes-to-404-error-page/22465969#22465969

But still, I'm not a success. Please help me with this issue.

**Note: I've tried to replace "paged" to "page" from here**

```
(get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

but same result.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a custom page template and not just archive-videos.php with the main loop?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using custom template, not main loop or archive-videos.php file. 
How can i use pagination with custom template?

Comment: Why are you doing it that way? You're essentially making an archive, so why not just use the archive?

Comment: I need to show my all post list with pagination like this view http://l7pic.com/index.php/work/ is it possible to use the archive and get a unique link for all? because the client wants to use a custom link, like http://l7pic.com/index.php/work/ or http://l7pic.com/index.php/our-all-videos, etc.

Comment: Yes. Just set `has_archive` to the slug that you want to use for the archive.

Comment: I've just set false for has_archive, http://prntscr.com/o6dmxq Can you write a code for me?